# Use jmx to change camel route path

Tags: java, apache-camel, jmx

I would like to do this pseudocode:

```
if (jmxobject foo==true) do this step in camel route;
else skip this step;
```

using camel and jmx.
I know that it is an easy thing to do but I would like to know the "best" way to do it:

1. Using less Java code as possible
2. Using a "camel recommended" way if there is one.

Thanks,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

See the content based router eip
http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

Then you need a predicate to check for the jmx object is true. And for that you can write some java code in a method that returns a boolean.